# Non-resolvable parent POM in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, sts

whenever i am importing an application into my STS workspace it is showing the error

i did mvn clean install same error i got, tried with maven update it is also failing and did google stuff also. There they are saying to add a relative path because parent is pointinf to artifact ID which is not present in my local.

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.test.tdpa:tdpa-tap-user-web:2.1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.test.tpa:ap-web-parent-pom:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 12, column 10
@
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.test.tpa:tpa-ap-user-web:2.1.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\rrajput8\git\tpa-ap-user-web\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.test.tpa:tpa-ap-user-web:2.1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.test.tpa:ap-web-parent-pom:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 12, column 10 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException

Comment: Could you add the important part of your pom.xml please, otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: hi @ThiloSchwarz i resolved the error this happens becaiuse settings.xml is pointing to wrong location